# Where to put migration within a Laravel 5.1 package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

Well, I do have a package take I only use alongside with my system. I do have migrations for that package (it was build on Laravel 4.2, and I'm upgrading it).

That being said: **On my package** (former workbench) **on Laravel 5.1, where do I put and how do I run my migrations?**

Does any of you guys know how to deal with this?

**UPDATE**:

This is not the case of a simple migration. Back on laravel 4.*, we were able to maintain migrations for each package (if it was so desirable), and I do have some migrations been held by my own package, in it's own database, with it's own table. So... I need it to be a **PACKAGE**'s migrations and not a **ROOT INSTALATION**'s migration.

Comment: Read [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) fully ?

Comment: I think I did! (I was sure I did till you pointed it out... now I'm scared to ensure!)

Comment: Do you want to create a `migration` or run the `migration`?

Comment: Both! But, I already have them. Just want to run, or further more, create.

Comment: just put them in `/database/migrations` to run, in command prompt type `php artisan migrate` (in your root project). note: you might need to tune your code a little.

Comment: .... ok, but I needed not to be a root system's migration, but a package's migration instead.

Comment: package should go into `/vendor` - wait, did you install it using composer or manually? well, i'm starting to wonder, is it possible for [package](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages) having it's own migrations?

Comment: I think it does...

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages#publishing-file-groups

Comment: and yes, `vendor:publish` just copy views to `/views` and migrations to `/database/migrations` - thus, after being published, we still need to run `php artisan migrate`. in the end, it just like put them in migrations folder. am i wrong?

Comment: I think you're right, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it in `packages/.../src/migrations`.
To run it:

1. You can insert in composer.json :

`"autoload": {
"classmap": [
    "database",
    "packages/.../src/migrations"
],`

2. Or just call :

   - Laravel 4.x `php artisan migrate --package="{vendor}/{name}"`
   - Laravel 5.x `php artisan migrate --path=/packages/.../migrations`

For more info : check [this blog from websanova.com](https://websanova.com/blog/laravel/creating-a-new-package-in-laravel-5-part-4-database-migrations-and-seeding)

Comment: I accidentally upvoted this answer even though it didn't work for me. This other one did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50499101/470749

Answer (score 2):

### Updated Answer for Laravel 5.6+

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#migrations says:

> If your package contains database migrations, you may use the
>   loadMigrationsFrom method to inform Laravel how to load them. The
>   loadMigrationsFrom method accepts the path to your package's
>   migrations as its only argument:

```
/**
 * Perform post-registration booting of services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/migrations');
}
```

> Once your package's migrations have been registered, they will
>   automatically be run when the  php artisan migrate command is
>   executed. You do not need to export them to the application's main
>   database/migrations directory.

The forward-slash is important. In my case, I used: `$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . "/migrations");`.

Answer (score -1):

To create a `migration`:

1. Go to `command prompt` locate your project root folder and run this command: `php artisan make:migration yourMigrationFileName --create=tableName`
2. You can found your migration file in `yourProjectFolder\database\migrations\timestamp_yourMigrationFileName.php`
3. Create your table.

To run the `migration`:

1. Go to `command prompt` locate your project root folder and run this command: `php artisan migrate`

And don't forget to declare your table name in your `Model`. You can do it by writing `protected $table = 'tableName'` in your model.

Comment: to be precise, it's not some date, it's timestamp.

Comment: @Tezla I am sorry for that, but this is not the issue. The timestamp will created by Laravel itself.

Comment: This is just a standart migration. Of that I read on the docs.